# How is the formula for the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor derived?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, terminology, capacitance

I have seen in I.E. Irodov that if the permittivity is given as $\epsilon$ then we can find the [capacitance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance#Capacitors) as $$C = \frac{\epsilon A}{d}$$ but I wonder whether it is dimensionally correct or not and how it is obtained?

Comment: Hi @satyatch. If you use dollar marks $\$$ around your text,  you can make good-looking math and formulas. See here http://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex. If you could edit your question to be more clear, it would help me to understand it better.

Comment: Is this the equation you are refering to? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance#Capacitors $$C=\epsilon_r\epsilon_0\frac{A}{d}$$

Comment: @steeven Yes I am asking that but what is  the proof of it.

Comment: Do you know about gaussian surfaces?

Comment: Google it http://www.google.com/search?q=capacitance+parallel+plates+gauss

Answer (score 3):

We have the surface charge density as 
charge/area. Now consider
[image: dont mind the light]